# Como funciona EntireRow.Hidden

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Prueba()
    Dim cell As Range
    
    For Each cell In Range("Tabla3[DIF $ ACUMULADA]")
        
        If cell.Value < 1000 And cell.Value >= -1000 Then
            Range("Tabla3[DIF $ ACUMULADA]").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Deberías ser más específico con tu pregunta. Exactamente a qué te refieres? ¿Al funcionamiento en si de la propiedad Hidden? ¿Al funcionamiento de esa rutina?

Comment: Creo que lo que quieres es `cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True` en vez de `Range("Tabla3[DIF $ ACUMULADA]").EntireRow.Hidden = True`

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar. La verdad es que no se que pasó con la pregunta per ce...en fin. Lo que quiero es que todos los valores, en una columna determinada, que sean menores al valor de una celda, A1 por ejemplo, y mayor al valor de otra celda, A2, que toda la fila se esconda. Es decir, que los valores entre 100 y -100 se esconda la fila completa, y que pueda modificar esos valores en las celdas a1 y A2

Comment: Te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y añadas esta información nueva, así como un ejemplo de los datos que tienes y el resultado esperado